# increase size of icon inside a button in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following button composable

```
@Composable
fun AppleLoginButton(onLoginClicked: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.size(44.dp),
        contentPadding = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
        onClick = {
            onLoginClicked()
    },
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Black, contentColor = Color.White)
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_apple_logo), contentDescription = "Apple logo")
    }
}
```

But I want to increase the size of the apple logo as its too small.

I have tried

```
modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either increase size of Button or not a height. Because it uses contentPadding which is 16.dp on both sides and leaves space. You can set it as `contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)`, have a button with no size modifier, or bigger modifier or use `IconButton`.

```
Text("Button")
Button(
    modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp),
    onClick = {
    },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor = Color.Black,
        contentColor = Color.White,
    ),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
) {
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_12),
        contentDescription = "Apple logo"
    )
}

Text("IconButton")

IconButton(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(48.dp)
        .background(Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
    onClick = {

    }
) {
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_12),
        contentDescription = "Apple logo",
        tint = Color.White
    )
}

Text("IconButton clip or shadow with clip=true ,0.dp elevation")
IconButton(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
//        .shadow(0.dp, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), clip = true)
        .size(48.dp)
        .background(Color.Black),
    onClick = {

    }
) {
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_12),
        contentDescription = "Apple logo",
        tint = Color.White
    )
}
```

Comment: That worked ok for the icon. However, the corners are not rounded when changing to the IconButton. I tried to adjust like this but it didn't work. `modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Black).size(44.dp)
            .border(width = Dp.Hairline, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), color = Color.Black),` Is there a way to get rounded corners on a IconButton?

Comment: Sure. You can make any compoasble any default shape like RoundedCorner, CutCorner or Circle or your custom shapes. Modifier.background(color, shape), or Modifier.clip(shape) or Modifier.shadow(elevation, clip, shape)